# Comparing values in mysql based on timestamp and identify trends

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a table in mysql database like below

```
id_indicator value trend date_data
           1     0     0 2011-08-18 09:16:15
           1     2     1 2011-08-18 10:16:15
           1     1    -1 2011-08-18 11:16:15
           1     2     1 2011-08-18 12:16:15
           2    21     0 2011-08-18 13:16:15
           2    21     0 2011-08-18 14:16:15
           2    21     0 2011-08-18 15:16:15
           3     3     0 2011-08-18 16:16:15
           3     4     1 2011-08-18 17:16:15
           3     4     0 2011-08-18 18:16:15
           4     4     0 2011-08-18 19:16:15
```

The table contain indicators and its values based on time and another column trend which is based on values. Initially all the trend is 0 then if next indicator value goes up than trend should be 1, if values goes down than trend should be -1, if value unchanged than trend should be 0.

But I have figured out that some of the trend values are not correctly entered into the table. Now I need help to identify how many trend value are inserted wrong also count group by indicator value.

I would be much appreciate for your help

Thanks

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - besides, the data set is completely correct, so there's nothing to do here except perhaps remove the redundant 'trend' column altogether.

Comment: the data I have given is not real data but this is table structure. real data contain lots of incorrect trends values also data here all important because it came in difference time

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509627/mysql-how-to-keep-track-of-change-in-value-using-its-trend/41510223  These appear to be homework questions

Answer (score 0):

You could use a correlated subquery to lookup the previous value.

```
SELECT
     *,
     (SELECT lookup.value
        FROM yourTable  AS lookup
       WHERE lookup.id_indicator = yourTable.id_indicator
         AND lookup.date_data < yourTable.date_data
    ORDER BY lookup.date_data DESC
       LIMIT 1
     )   AS previous_value
FROM
    yourTable
```

Comment: I am not getting any results