# MySQL : How to keep track of change in value using its trend?

Tags: mysql

MYSQL : How to keep track of change in value using its trend, if value decreases then trend would be -1, if increases then 1 and 0 for same

For example

```
id_indicator    value      Trend                
    1             0           0   
    1             1           1                                        
    1             5           1                               
    1             4           -1                                 
    2             1           0                      
    2             -8          -1                               
    2             0           1
```

How i can get trend column?
Can i add temporary column in Select statement that will hold trend value?

Comment: Please, explain, what you mean by saying: "How i can get trend column?". What exactly do you want to get?

Comment: Without knowing your table structure it's impossible to help you. And even then I doubt that this is easily done in mysql. You should either do this the moment you insert a new row (insert the trend as a column) or do that calculation in another programming language.

Comment: Trend column value. using column 'value'.

Comment: if previous value> current value then trend = -1.

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY? How can we tell if one row is before or after another row?

Comment: @ChrisCaviness then is it possible using procedure?

Comment: Thanks for the try @ChrisCaviness

Comment: @Soni007 I'm not sure that the advice you've received from other contributors is entirely accurate. If you have a PK, the problem is trivial. If you don't have a PK, then you don't really have a table.

Comment: @Strawberry, primary key is there its created using sequence.

Comment: If we can't see it, it's not there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653899/comparing-values-in-mysql-based-on-timestamp-and-identify-trends  Shame on you, don't use SO to get answers to your homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a myslq variable to keep track of previous rows

```
SET @prev = 0;

SELECT 
    id_indicator, 
    value, 
    -- IF(value > @prev, 1, IF(value < @prev , -1, 0)) AS trend,
    SIGN(value-@prev) AS trend, -- nicer solution thx to @spencer7593
    @prev:=value FROM `the_table`
```

the fourth column's only purpose is to assign the current value into `@prev` so you can use it in the next row iteration.
having both current and previous values, you can pretty much write any expression you want with them

Comment: In the absence of an ORDER BY clause, this solution is meaningless. Otherwise excellent.

Comment: or, `SIGN(value-@prev) AS trend`

Comment: @csminb, thanks for the suggestion, sorry what is '@prev:= price',

Comment: @Soni007 `@prev:= price` typo ;) it should be @prev:= value -- tested it on a table witch had price

Comment: nevermind, this is a clearly a homework question.  Deleting my answer.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653899/comparing-values-in-mysql-based-on-timestamp-and-identify-trends